# duda con XSL Schema

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-schema

En un curso que estoy haciendo nos proponen un ejercicio en el que, si mal no entiendo, debemos rellenar el archivo xsd de forma que cumpla la estructura de un xml.

**XML**

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<contabilidad xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="factura.xsd">
  <factura codigo="0001A" fecha="2010-02-28">
   <cliente>
      <cif>B80000000</cif>
      <nombre>Cliente 01</nombre>
      <calle>Del arte</calle>
      <numero>33</numero>
      <postal>28033</postal>
      <ciudad>Madrid</ciudad>
     <localidad>Madrid</localidad>
    </cliente>
    <desglose>
      <linea>
        <concepto>Concepto 1</concepto>
        <cantidad>1</cantidad>
        <precio_unidad>16</precio_unidad>
        <precio_total>16</precio_total>
      </linea>
      <linea>
        <concepto>Concepto 2</concepto>
        <cantidad>3</cantidad>
        <precio_unidad>10</precio_unidad>
        <precio_total>30</precio_total>
      </linea>
    </desglose>
    <forma_pago>
      <tipo>T</tipo>
      <dias>30</dias>
    </forma_pago>
    <observaciones>
      A la atención del Sr.Fernandez
    </observaciones>
    <totales>
      <subtotal>46</subtotal>
      <iva_porciento>18</iva_porciento>
      <iva_precio>8.28</iva_precio>
      <total>54.28</total>
    </totales>
  </factura>
  <factura codigo="0002A" fecha="2010-02-28">
    <cliente>
      <cif>B80000000</cif>
      <nombre>Cliente 01</nombre>
      <calle>Del arte</calle>
      <numero>33</numero>
      <postal>28033</postal>
      <ciudad>Madrid</ciudad>
      <localidad>Madrid</localidad>
    </cliente>
    <desglose>
      <linea>
        <concepto>Concepto 1</concepto>
        <cantidad>5</cantidad>
        <precio_unidad>5</precio_unidad>
        <precio_total>25</precio_total>
      </linea>
      <linea>
        <concepto>Concepto 2</concepto>
        <cantidad>20</cantidad>
        <precio_unidad>15</precio_unidad>
        <precio_total>300</precio_total>
      </linea>
      <linea>
        <concepto>Concepto 3</concepto>
        <cantidad>1</cantidad>
        <precio_unidad>7.5</precio_unidad>
        <precio_total>7.5</precio_total>
      </linea>
    </desglose>
    <forma_pago>
      <tipo>P</tipo>
      <dias>60</dias>
    </forma_pago>
    <observaciones>
      Confirmar recepcion de factura
    </observaciones>
    <totales>
      <subtotal>332.5</subtotal>
      <iva_porciento>18</iva_porciento>
      <iva_precio>59.85</iva_precio>
      <total>392.35</total>
    </totales>
  </factura>
  <factura codigo="0003A" fecha="2010-02-28">
    <cliente>
      <cif>B80001118</cif>
      <nombre>Cliente 02</nombre>
      <calle>Caleruega</calle>
      <numero>67</numero>
      <postal>28008</postal>
      <ciudad>Madrid</ciudad>
      <localidad>Madrid</localidad>
    </cliente>
    <desglose>
      <linea>
        <concepto>Concepto 1</concepto>
        <cantidad>36</cantidad>
        <precio_unidad>2</precio_unidad>
        <precio_total>72</precio_total>
      </linea>
      <linea>
        <concepto>Concepto 2</concepto>
        <cantidad>8</cantidad>
        <precio_unidad>5</precio_unidad>
        <precio_total>40</precio_total>
      </linea>
    </desglose>
    <forma_pago>
      <tipo>C</tipo>
      <dias>90</dias>
    </forma_pago>
    <observaciones>

    </observaciones>
    <totales>
      <subtotal>112</subtotal>
      <iva_porciento>18</iva_porciento>
      <iva_precio>20.16</iva_precio>
      <total>132.16</total>
    </totales>
  </factura>
  <factura codigo="0004A" fecha="2010-02-28">
    <cliente>
      <cif>B80001118</cif>
      <nombre>Cliente 02</nombre>
      <calle>Caleruega</calle>
      <numero>67</numero>
      <postal>28008</postal>
      <ciudad>Madrid</ciudad>
      <localidad>Madrid</localidad>
    </cliente>
    <desglose>
      <linea>
        <concepto>Concepto 1</concepto>
        <cantidad>68</cantidad>
        <precio_unidad>2</precio_unidad>
        <precio_total>136</precio_total>
      </linea>
      <linea>
        <concepto>Concepto 2</concepto>
        <cantidad>10</cantidad>
        <precio_unidad>96</precio_unidad>
        <precio_total>960</precio_total>
      </linea>
      <linea>
        <concepto>Concepto 3</concepto>
        <cantidad>42</cantidad>
        <precio_unidad>2</precio_unidad>
        <precio_total>84</precio_total>
      </linea>
      <linea>
        <concepto>Concepto 4</concepto>
        <cantidad>10</cantidad>
        <precio_unidad>0.5</precio_unidad>
        <precio_total>5</precio_total>
      </linea>
    </desglose>
    <forma_pago>
      <tipo>T</tipo>
      <dias>30</dias>
    </forma_pago>
    <observaciones>
      Pendiente de recibir justificante de transferencia
    </observaciones>
    <totales>
      <subtotal>1182</subtotal>
      <iva_porciento>18</iva_porciento>
      <iva_precio>212.76</iva_precio>
      <total>1394.76</total>
    </totales>
  </factura>
  <factura codigo="0005A" fecha="2010-02-28">
    <cliente>
      <cif>B80002526</cif>
      <nombre>Cliente 03</nombre>
      <calle>Avenida de madrid</calle>
      <numero>2</numero>
      <postal>28750</postal>
      <ciudad>Madrid</ciudad>
      <localidad>San Agustin del Guadalix</localidad>
    </cliente>
    <desglose>
      <linea>
        <concepto>Concepto 1</concepto>
        <cantidad>3</cantidad>
        <precio_unidad>152</precio_unidad>
        <precio_total>456</precio_total>
      </linea>
      <linea>
        <concepto>Concepto 2</concepto>
        <cantidad>265</cantidad>
        <precio_unidad>0.5</precio_unidad>
        <precio_total>132.5</precio_total>
      </linea>
    </desglose>
    <forma_pago>
      <tipo>T</tipo>
      <dias>90</dias>
    </forma_pago>
    <observaciones>
      Factura correspondiente al mes de febrero
    </observaciones>
    <totales>
      <subtotal>588.5</subtotal>
      <iva_porciento>18</iva_porciento>
      <iva_precio>105.93</iva_precio>
      <total>694.43</total>
    </totales>
  </factura>
  <factura codigo="0006A" fecha="2010-02-28">
    <cliente>
      <cif>B80002526</cif>
      <nombre>Cliente 03</nombre>
      <calle>Avenida de madrid</calle>
      <numero>2</numero>
      <postal>28750</postal>
      <ciudad>Madrid</ciudad>
      <localidad>San Agustin del Guadalix</localidad>
    </cliente>
    <desglose>
      <linea>
        <concepto>Concepto 1</concepto>
        <cantidad>9</cantidad>
        <precio_unidad>15</precio_unidad>
        <precio_total>135</precio_total>
      </linea>
      <linea>
        <concepto>Concepto 2</concepto>
        <cantidad>2</cantidad>
        <precio_unidad>180</precio_unidad>
        <precio_total>360</precio_total>
      </linea>
      <linea>
        <concepto>Concepto 3</concepto>
        <cantidad>9</cantidad>
        <precio_unidad>1</precio_unidad>
        <precio_total>9</precio_total>
      </linea>
      <linea>
        <concepto>Concepto 4</concepto>
        <cantidad>26</cantidad>
        <precio_unidad>31</precio_unidad>
        <precio_total>806</precio_total>
      </linea>
      <linea>
        <concepto>Concepto 5</concepto>
        <cantidad>17</cantidad>
        <precio_unidad>6</precio_unidad>
        <precio_total>102</precio_total>
      </linea>
      <linea>
        <concepto>Concepto 6</concepto>
        <cantidad>3</cantidad>
        <precio_unidad>75</precio_unidad>
        <precio_total>225</precio_total>
      </linea>
    </desglose>
    <forma_pago>
      <tipo>P</tipo>
      <dias>30</dias>
    </forma_pago>
    <observaciones>

    </observaciones>
    <totales>
      <subtotal>1637</subtotal>
      <iva_porciento>18</iva_porciento>
      <iva_precio>294.66</iva_precio>
      <total>1931.66</total>
    </totales>
  </factura>
</contabilidad>
```

**XSD**

```
?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="contabilidad">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="factura" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" >

         <xs:annotation>
           <xs:documentation>
             De esta forma obligamos a que minimo tiene que aparecer 1 vez, pero pueden existir todos los que se quiera
           </xs:documentation>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>

                <xs:element name="cliente" maxOccurs="3" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string" use="required">
                    <xs:annotation>
                     <xs:documentation>
                            Solo puede exitir un xs:elemento cliente por factura
                     </xs:documentation>
                   </xs:annotation>
                <xs:complexType>

                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="cif" maxOccurs="3" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string" use="required">
                      <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>
                        El cif tiene que ser segun el xs:pattern
                        </xs:documentation>
                      </xs:annotation>
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                          <xs:minLength value="9"/>
                          <xs:maxLength value="9"/>
                          <xs:pattern value="([A-Z]{1}[0-9]{8})"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="nombre" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string" use="required">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                          <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="calle" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string" use="required">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                          <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="numero" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="xs:integer" use="required">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                        </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="postal" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string" use="required">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                          <xs:pattern value="([0-9]{5})"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="ciudad" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string" use="required">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                          <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="localidad" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string" use="required">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                          <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>

              <xs:element name="desglose" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string" use="required">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="linea" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" >
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="concepto" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string" use="required">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                              <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
                              </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                          </xs:element>
                          <xs:element name="cantidad" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="xs:integer" use="required">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                              <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                              </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                          </xs:element>
                          <xs:element name="precio_unidad" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="xs:decimal" use="required">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                              <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                              </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                          </xs:element>
                          <xs:element name="precio_total" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="xs:decimal" use="required">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                              <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                              </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="forma_pago" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="string" use="required">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="tipo" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="string" use="required">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                          <xs:enumeration value="T"/>
                          <xs:enumeration value="C"/>
                          <xs:enumeration value="P"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="dias" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="string" use="required">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                          <xs:enumeration value="30"/>
                          <xs:enumeration value="60"/>
                          <xs:enumeration value="90"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="observaciones" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="string" use="optional">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:maxLength value="100"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="totales" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="decimal" use="required">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="subtotal" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="decimal" use="required">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                        </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="iva_porciento" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="decimal" use="required">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                        </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="iva_precio" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="decimal" use="required">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                        </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="total" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="decimal" use="required">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                        </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>

            <xs:attribute name="codigo" use="required" type="string">
              <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                  <xs:pattern value="([0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1})"/>
                </xs:restriction>
              </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
            <xs:attribute name="fecha" use="required" type="xs:date">
              <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:date">
                </xs:restriction>
              </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

La cuestión, es que, ya de primeras, estoy muy verde en el tema... y después lo que no consigo entender es qué hay que hacer. Según me han comentado tengo que definir que elemento será de clase string..., definir patrones de elementos... pero por lo que veo en el xsd ya está todo definido!!

Por favor, a ver si me podéis echar una mano al respecto y viendo los archivos me aclaráis que veis vosotros para ver si puedo orientarme y avanzar en el ejercicio, porque estoy muy atascado...

Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Pero, ¿qué duda tienes exactamente? xsd para lo que vale es para estructurar tu fichero xml. Esto se puede hacer de dos formas, con un DTD o con un XSD. El primero sólo define la estructura, el segundo define estructura y formato, pero si no indicas exáctamente qué duda tienes poco podremos ayudarte.

Comment: pues ese es el problema, se supone que mirando los dos archivos debo ver que falta código por añadir en ambos, (por ejemplo definir que elemento será de clase string..., definir patrones de elementos...) pero no tengo ni idea.